# In Sublime Text how do you short-cut writing code?

Tags: sublime-text-2

My apologies but I do not know what its called, if this has been asked or what Stack site this is best suited for.  I've seen several videos on how people use Sublime to create quicker tags and I would like to learn the proper way to do this if there is any documentation or what I can do quicker in my coding.

In several videos I see people doing things like:

`div.class` and it will create `<div class="class"></div>` after `tab`.

Comment: You can also create your own custom snippets; http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html

Comment: The above link is no longer valid. Is there an official link which state how to create our own custom snippets ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The feature you describe is part of Sublime Text 2 out of the box. Make sure your document uses HTML syntax (*View » Syntax » HTML*).

Type `foo.bar`, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and you'll get `<foo class="bar"></foo>`. There's also `foo#bar` (for `id` instead of `class`). Both are implemented in *`Packages`*`/HTML/html_completions.py`.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to build-out `a` tags and something like `li` tags?  Is this only for HTML? and +1.

Comment: @Gramps Not sure what you mean, but note that I pointed out the script where this feature is implemented (select the *Browse Packages…* menu item to go to the directory I mention). You could, for example, extend the existing script to support e.g. additional separators. Sublime Text 2 scripts are implemented in Python, [here's the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org), and [this page](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) contains the documentation specific to Sublime Text 2.

Comment: I've seen somebody do `div#main.container` but Sublime spits out a `main` element with a class of `container` when I try?

Answer (score 8):

#### Emmet / Zen-Coding

[Emmet](https://emmet.io/) is a plugin where you write the basic structure in a CSS-selector-like manner and have the editor expand it. You can find the [package on GitHub](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) and install it through the Package manager.

[image]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/multiplication.gif))</sub>

This Smashing Magazine has [an article on it](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/goodbye-zen-coding-hello-emmet/). For example,

```
(.foo>h1)+(.bar>h2)
```

will expand with <kbd>Tab</kbd> to

```
<div class="foo">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
<div class="bar">
  <h2></h2>
</div>
```

#### Wrap Selection in Tags

What you can also do is press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to create an open tag or wrap the current selection in a tag (see *Edit » Tag » Wrap Current Selection in Tag*).

By default it'll create:

```
<p></p>
```

with the tag name selected so you can overwrite it.

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> would further get you inside the tag. Or, if you press <kbd>Space</kbd>, you could create attributes, for example:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (on Windows/Linux) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> on OS X
- <kbd>A</kbd>
- <kbd>Space</kbd>
- Type `href="..."`, then <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Results in `<a href="..."></a>` with the cursor positioned inside the tag

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to make it work in the current version of sublime is to type

`Ctrl + Shift + p`

and look for

`Set Syntax : PHP`

and the above

`div.class`

followed by `TAB` should give

`<div class="class"> </div>`