# What is this texteditor's counterpart in Windows?

Tags: mac, text-editors, plugins, sublime-text-2, css

1. I am learning CSS and want to know what the following texteditor is:

[image]

Is there a counterpart for Windows?

2. There seems to be a Sublime plugin, when you type:

   div.classname

then perhaps press some key, it automatically turns into:

```
<div class="classname">
</div>
```

What could this plugin be?

Comment: maybe [liveeditor](http://liveditor.com/index.php) can do the same.

Comment: Hi J.Joe, welcome to Super User! Please, try to avoid asking multiple questions in a single post, since it could lead to confussion, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 1. It doesn't seem that there is a version of Espresso for Windows but maybe you can try Liveditor 
http://liveditor.com/blog/espresso-css-editor-for-windows/

Answer (score 0):

**1. Espresso alternative for Windows**

There is no direct port or counterpart of Espresso for Windows, but there are several similar live-editing applications available such as [Brackets](http://brackets.io/).

**2. Short-hand for div.classname**

As @daniel-beck mentions this functionality already exists in Sublime Text:

> The feature you describe is part of Sublime Text 2 out of the box.
>   Make sure your document uses HTML syntax (View » Syntax » HTML).
>
> Type foo.bar, press Tab, and you'll get .
>   There's also foo#bar (for id instead of class). Both are implemented
>   in Packages/HTML/html_completions.py.

**Reference:**

- [Is there anolog of Espresso for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285532/is-there-analog-of-espresso-for-windows)
- [In Sublime Text how do you short-cut writing code?](https://superuser.com/questions/706016/in-sublime-text-how-do-you-short-cut-writing-code)